# ng-repeat is not returning a list of posts

Tags: wp-api

I am currently trying my hand at creating a WP theme using angular JS.
I am trying to work through this tutorial: https://1fix.io/blog/2014/11/05/angularjs-json-api-wp-theme/

However, I am near the end of this, and my ng-repeat is not returning a list of my posts.

This is my scripts.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'main.html',
    controller: 'Main'
})
.when('/:ID', {
    templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'content.html',
    controller: 'Content'
    });
})
     .controller('Main', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
     $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts/').then(function(res){
    $scope.posts = res;
    });
})
.controller('Content', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts' + $routeParams.id).then(function(res){
        $scope.post = res;
    });
});
```

And this is the code from my main.html:

```
<div ng-controller="Main">
<strong>This is the main page</strong>

<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <a href="{{ post.id }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, when I navigate to my page I only see:

[image]

All the scripts seem to be enqueued correctly, and index.php is pulling main.html through, it just doesn't work.

I know it'll be something obvious, but my google foo has let me down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the tutorial you linked is using `success`, and you've changed it to `then`.

The `success` method has been [deprecated](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice), so you were correct to do that. However, because `then` returns data a little differently from `success`, you'll need to update your `$scope.post` variable accordingly:

`$scope.post = res.data;`

You can find a great explanation for the change in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/3194942).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for your help, I feel a bit stupid I couldn't find that answer myself now. Also, thanks for including a link to the explanation as well

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the post format generated by the REST API I think you should access the title like:

```
 <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <a href="{{ post.id }}">{{ post.title.rendered }}</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working for me either

Comment: And the `{ {post.id }}` - is this part working?

Comment: Sorry, no that bit doesn't seem to work either.